# Class Method Not Returning Value When Accessed Via Inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have a class method that stops returning a value when I try accessing through an inherited subclass.

Have no idea what's causing it to not return the appropriate value.

Here's what I have:

```py
class KNN():    
    def __init__(self, neighbors=5, centered=True):
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        self.centered  = centered

    def _get_distance(self, xi):
        return np.sqrt(((xi - self.X_fit)**2).sum(1))

    def fit(self, X, y):
        if self.centered:
            self.X_fit = standardize(X)
        else:
            self.X_fit = X
        self.y_fit     = y

    def predict(self, X, centered=False):
        m, n              = X.shape[0], self.X_fit.shape[0]
        self.dist_matrix  = np.zeros((m, n))
        X_pred            = np.zeros(X.shape)

        if standardize:
           X_pred  = standardize(X)
        else:
           X_pred  = X

        for row in range(m):
            self.dist_matrix[row] = self._get_distance(X_pred[row])

        self.idx_vals      = np.argsort(self.dist_matrix)[:, :self.neighbors]
        self.y_idx         = self.y_fit[self.idx_vals]
        self.preds         = [self.neighbor_calculation(self.y_idx[i]) for i in range(len(self.y_idx))]
        return self.preds
```

If I access the `KNN` class directly the `predict` method works as intended, and it returns an array of the predicted values.

However, it stops when I try and create a subclass that inherits from `KNN`:

```
class KNNClassifier(KNN):
    def predict(self, X, centered=False):
        self.neighbor_calculation = majority_vote
        super().predict(X, standardize)
```

When I access the `predict` method through the `KNNClassifier` class it doesn't return a value.

However, `self.preds` contains the actual predictions.

But trying something like `KNNClassifier.predict(X)[:10]` gives the error message:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'
```

I don't know why the returned value is suddenly being interpreted as `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `super` to call the parent method from the child, which is right, but you need to use `return` to return the value:

```
return super().predict(X, standardize)
```